# Negative Dimensions Error running tensorflow tutorial

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I just finished the TensorFlow [MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) for beginners. I'm running the latest version of TensorFlow in Jupyter (locally installed) on Python 3.

My code is the following, basically taken verbatim from the tutorial:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import sys
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_,logits=y)
sess= tf.InteractiveSession()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.05).minimize(cross_entropy)
for i in range(1000):
batch_x,batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_x,y:batch_y})
```

I thought that maybe the issue was with the python3. So, I tried running the same code in a python 2.7 version of tensor flow. Nothing changed.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1138     try:
-> 1139       return fn(*args)
   1140     except errors.OpError as e:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1120                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1121                                  status, run_metadata)
   1122 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     88             try:
---> 89                 next(self.gen)
     90             except StopIteration:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: Shape [-1,10] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-89eb8cf9286c> in <module>()
      1 for _ in range(1000):
      2     batch_x,batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
----> 3     sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_x,y:batch_y})

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    787     try:
    788       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 789                          run_metadata_ptr)
    790       if run_metadata:
    791         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    995     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    996       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 997                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    998     else:
    999       results = []

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1130     if handle is None:
   1131       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1132                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1133     else:
   1134       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1150         except KeyError:
   1151           pass
-> 1152       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1153 
   1154   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Shape [-1,10] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder_1', defined at:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2698, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2802, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-c355762e89a9>", line 2, in <module>
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1530, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1954, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1,10] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think it would be useful to have a fix for the error in this tutorial.

RESOLVED! Very stupid error. In the last line, I wrote y, when I needed to write y_. If someone could explain to me why this mistake produced the error message it does, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this error is produced lies in a type in this line of your code:

```
sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y})
```

Instead you should have written:

```
sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_x, y_:batch_y})
```

What happens is that you are trying to feed a batch of 100 labels to a varibale, that is designed to hold a single value.

**y** is the output of the model that you've implemented here:

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)
```

While **y_** represents a tensor of size `[100,10]` that you've first created a placeholder variable for. For each training iteration you're then loading a batch of 100 examples, that are fed to the session:

```
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
batch_x,batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_x,y_:batch_y})
```

I guess that your confusion results from the fact that during `session.run()`  one has to assign `batch_x` to `x`, while `batch_y` is fed in `y_`. The reason for this is that the training images (**x**) are coming from the MNIST dataset and so are the correct labels (**y_**), while your models output / the prediction (**y**) is computed by your Convolutional Neural Network.

You feed your Session with a batch of input images. Your model makes a prediction for each images of which class it hinks that this images belongs to and finally these predictions are compared with the correct labels. The last of these step is performed in the following line of your code:

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_,logits=y)
```

As you can see the cross entropy function is called by passing it the correct labels that are coming from your dataset and the predictions, that are computed 'on the fly' by your model. That is why **y_** has to be passed data to during the session run, while it is not neccessary to do the same for **y**.